# I have a name error and not exactly sure where to define my argument

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, command-line-interface

I'm making an guitar browsing CLI project. I have the name and url of different guitars like so:

```
def self.get_electric
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://reverb.com/c/electric-guitars"))

        electrics = []
        counter = 0

        while counter < doc.css("h2:contains('Popular Electric Guitars')+div.overflowing-row__items ul.tiles.tiles--single-row.tiles--grow.tiles--three-wide li.tiles__tile").length
        electric = {
            name: doc.css("h2:contains('Popular Electric Guitars')+div.overflowing-row__items ul.tiles.tiles--single-row.tiles--grow.tiles--three-wide li.tiles__tile")[counter].text,
            url: doc.css("h2:contains('Popular Electric Guitars')+div.overflowing-row__items ul.tiles.tiles--single-row.tiles--grow.tiles--three-wide li.tiles__tile a.marketing-callout__inner")[counter]["href"]
        }
        counter += 1
        electrics << electric
        end
        electrics
        HiStrung::Guitar.mass_create_electrics(electrics)
    end
```

If user types in 'electric' or 'acoustic' they will get the name of the guitar and the url:

```
Enter here: electric

1. Fender Telecaster - https://reverb.com/marketplace/electric-guitars?query=telecaster
2. Gibson Les Paul - https://reverb.com/marketplace?query=les%20paul
3. Fender Stratocaster - https://reverb.com/marketplace/electric-guitars?query=stratocaster
4. Gibson SG - https://reverb.com/marketplace?query=sg
5. Fender Jazzmaster - https://reverb.com/marketplace?query=jazzmaster
```

Now what I want my program to do is when a user types in the number for whichever guitar they want to know more about, it will show the price and description of that guitar. The price and description are in another url.

I'm trying to make a method that grabs the url and get the html for the price and description:

```
def self.get_electric_info(electric)
        url = electric.url
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML(url)
    end
```

but i'm getting this name error:

```
pry(main)> HiStrung::Scraper.get_electric_info(electric)
NameError: undefined local variable or method `electric' for main:Object
from (pry):1:in `__pry__'
```

Here is my initialize class:

```
class HiStrung::Guitar
attr_accessor :name, :url

@@electrics = []
@@acoustics = []

def self.electrics
    @@electrics
end

def self.acoustics
    @@acoustics
end

def self.mass_create_electrics(electric_hash)
    electric_hash.each do |e_hash|
        electric = HiStrung::Guitar.new(e_hash[:name], e_hash[:url])
        @@electrics << electric
    end
end

def self.mass_create_acoustics(acoustic_hash)
    acoustic_hash.each do |a_hash|
        acoustic = HiStrung::Guitar.new(a_hash[:name], a_hash[:url])
        @@acoustics << acoustic
    end
end

def initialize(name, url)
    @name, @url = name, url
end
```

end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't provide the context at the point where you are calling that method, but if you look in your code you'll see you don't have an `electric` variable defined.

Assign `electric` to the Guitar object you want information for before you invoke your method.

Do something like this:

```
electric = HiStrung::Guitar.new("My name", "My url")
HiStrung::Scraper.get_electric_info(electric)
```

That should fix the problem.

Comment: I did:  `electric = HiStrung::Guitar.new(name, url)
    def self.get_electric_info(electric)
       url = electric.url
       doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    end`

Comment: But i got: `/Users/tlreigns/RoyalTerminal/hi_strung/lib/hi_strung/scraper.rb:57:in ``<class:Scraper>'``: uninitialized constant HiStrung::Guitar (NameError)`  I required it in my environment.

Comment: It's a little hard to tell without the full context, but it sounds like you need to double check that your require and require_relative calls are correctly doing there job, and that they're in the right place.